# Is it possible to use SCOOP from inside a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, python-scoop

Is there a method to run the SCOOP module from within a Jupyter notebook? I need to use SCOOP to build datasets, and from there use matplotlib/seaborn to build plots.